# Highest interval between two dates same table

Tags: postgresql, date, intervals

I was searching a lot, and trying and trying again, I really don't know how to solve my problem, maybe because I don't know how SQL requirements works and treat tables.

Here is my problem. I have one table with columns (id, sentdate, data) . One of the column is date (sentdate) as example "2011-03-21 05:17:48". What I need is to compare first date with second and get the difference of days, then second with third and get difference of day...and so on. Finally I want to get the highest interval of day with the begin date and end date. I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: how do you determine what is beginning and end?

Comment: Have you tried `lag()` function from [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the difference in integer days:

```
select
    sentdate, lag(sentdate) over(order by sentdate) previous_sentdate,
    sentdate::date - lag(sentdate) over(order by sentdate) days
from t
order by sentdate
```